# Implementing Hierarchical State Machines in Labview

Tags: labview, state-machine

Is there any Design Pattern to implement Hierarchical State Machines in Labview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply place a state machine subVI inside an outer state machine's states. Swapping outer states could be done using straight up procedural programming, or using asynchronous user events, as see in the "Fault Trigger" event given here: http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/HierarchicalStateMachine.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work for you, but consider looking to TLB 
https://lavag.org/topic/16188-tlb-top-level-baseline-prime-application-template/

Comment: Nice link. I did't find an example about Hierarchical State Machines, but it's worth giving a look!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to build, you might get some mileage from http://www.ni.com/labview/statechart/

Answer (score 0):

Download the JKI state machine template and objects. I used the template, it's basically easy to use if you understand the concept. 
1- Place your sequential code in cases under New Category.
2- Initialize your data types that will be passed via the cluster under Data:Initialize.
3- Add lines at "Event Structure", "Idle" of the names of your code cases.